# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given. What?

Tags: php, mysqli

I made a PHP page that is supposed to select two names from a database and displays them.

It just says:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/tdoylex1/public_html/dorkhub/index.php on line 4
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/tdoylex1/public_html/dorkhub/index.php on line 8

My code is:

```
<?php mysqli_connect(localhost,tdoylex1_dork,dorkk,tdoylex1_dork);
$name1 = mysqli_query("SELECT name1 FROM users
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1");

$name2 = mysqli_query("SELECT name FROM users
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1");

?>

<title>DorkHub. The online name-rating website.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body bgcolor='EAEAEA'>
<center>
<div id='TITLE'>
    <h2>DorkHub. The online name-rating website.</h2>
</div>
    <p>
    <br>
    <h3><?php echo $name1; ?></h3><h4> against </h4><h3><?php echo $name1; ?></h3>
    <br><br>
    <h2 style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>Who's sounds the dorkiest?</h2>
    <br><br>
    <div id='vote'>
    <h3 id='done' style='margin-right: 10px'>VOTE FOR FIRST</h3><h3 id='done'>VOTE FOR LAST</h3>
```

Comment: You are missing a parameter. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: First lesson in doing programming: If an error message says you're missing something, chances are you're missing that thing.

Answer (score 33):

The issue is that you're not saving the mysqli connection. Change your connect to:

```
$aVar = mysqli_connect('localhost','tdoylex1_dork','dorkk','tdoylex1_dork');
```

And then include it in your query:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($aVar, "SELECT name1 FROM users
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1");
$aName1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
$name1 = $aName1['name1'];
```

Also don't forget to enclose your connections variables as strings as I have above. This is what's causing the error but you're using the function wrong, mysqli_query returns a query object but to get the data out of this you need to use something like mysqli_fetch_assoc http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php to actually get the data out into a variable as I have above.

Answer (score 5):

the `mysqli_query`excepts 2 parameters , first variable is `mysqli_connect`equivalent variable , second one is the query you have provided

```
$name1 = mysqli_connect(localhost,tdoylex1_dork,dorkk,tdoylex1_dork);

$name2 = mysqli_query($name1,"SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```